# Disable warning messages in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

When I plot a graph with `pgfplots` sometimes I got such warning message

```
NOTE: coordinate (500,0) has been dropped because of the y-coordinate filter.
```

However in may case such points are legal. How can I disable such NOTE messages.

Here is a code example:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmode=normal,ymode=log]
  \addplot table[x=k,y=Time]{fig_xxx.data};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can add the following to your preamble (or locally in the `axis` environment):

```
\pgfplotsset{filter discard warning=false}
```

This does exactly what you need. However it also removes warnings for unbounded coordinates.

Comment: Where can I find a full reference of `\pgfplotsset` commands? I want to remove also `Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (left?)` messages.

Comment: @jutky (remember to use the at<user>, then the user will get notified.) I have not encountered one key which is not in the manual. However they can be hard to find if one has no good search ground. But basically they are all there.

Comment: thanks. (also with at<user> it is more easy to get 15 characters to post a comment :) )

Comment: @jutky the warning "has no coordinates" cannot be disabled currently.

Comment: @Christian Feuersänger Thanks very much for that piece of information.