# \widthof text in a def'd subroutine inside a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, calculations, width

I have already seen [\widthof within tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8691/widthof-within-tikzpicture), but this is slightly different.

I have a rather complex Tikz image, which I'd like to eventually include in a Latex document; as such, I'd like this .tikz file to be as self contained as possible. There are a bunch of commands in there relevant to building the plot; unfortunately if I leave them as-is, I get [Wrong placement (and/or size) of picture / plot with groupplot of table (... and discontinuity)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183399/wrong-placement-and-or-size-of-picture-plot-with-groupplot-of-table-and) (even in a standalone .tex file). Specifically, if the commands execute between `{document}` and `{tikzpicture}`, then the extraneous space is generated; I could have the commands in preamble, but then the .tikz file will not be self-contained.

So, I thought I'd collect these commands in a `\def` subroutine, and have them run *inside* the `{tikzpicture}`. Unfortunately, one of those commands is `\widthof`, which I intended for measuring the width of the text "256" in the tiny font, and wanted to use that to set the x scale of the pgfplot. So I came to this MWE:

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{calc} %\widthof
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pagecolor{yellow!15}

% \newcommand\prepCmds{
\def\prepCmds{
  \newlength{\smlblwtmp}
  \setlength{\smlblwtmp}{\widthof{\tiny 256}}
  \global\let\smlblwid\smlblwtmp
  \typeout{smlblwid FIRST: \the\smlblwid}
}

% \prepCmds{} % smlblwid FIRST: 10.2085pt

\begin{document}

% \prepCmds{} % smlblwid FIRST: 10.2085pt

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \prepCmds{} % smlblwid FIRST: 0.0pt

  \begin{axis}[
    x=2*\smlblwid,
  ]
    \addplot {x*0.5};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As it can be seen, *only* when I call the `\prepCmds` inside `{tikzpicture}`, the `\widtgof` fails and returns 0 (everywhere else, it returns a correct number); when that happens, `pdflatex` shows this:

```
PGFPlots warning: The ticklabel anchor cannot be determined, the normal vector 
-(0.0pt,-1.0pt) and the unit y vector (0.0pt,1.00005pt) are almost parallel (ab
s(cos(angle)) = 1.00005pt)!
pgfplots@borderanchor@for@axis 1,2,3: y, 1v0, rectangle
```

One would say, as expected for x unit of 0 - but it took me *hours* to debug this so far: among other things, I inserted a `\message` in the pgfplots source so the arguments of `\pgfplots@borderanchor@for@axis` are plotted  (when the width is not zero, with `\prepCmds` running elsewhere, the arguments are `x, v00, rectangle`).

Obviously, all this boils down to `\widthof` returning 0 inside a `{tikzpicture}`; now that I know this, I guess I could move just the `\widthof` calculation out of the subroutine. However, I'd still prefer for the `\widthof` calculation to be inside the subroutine, for self-containment reasons, so I would like to ask: why is `\widthof` inside a `{tikzpicture}` zero; and is there some sort of a trick (maybe "globalize" some tikz intern variables?) that would make `\widthof` work inside a `{tikzpicture}` properly?

Comment: First of all move `\newlength{\smlblwtmp}` ***outside*** the definition of `\prepCmds`. About the specific problem: inside a `tikzpicture`, the current font is set to `\nullfont` that has no character, so the width you're measuring is zero.

Comment: Many thanks @egreg - that explains it; if you don't mind posting that as an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers!

Comment: I'd rather close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, damn. I have a hammer. please let us know if you want to keep it open. I didn't know that it closes right away

Comment: @egreg: sure - closure sounds good, the answer is in the comments anyways (as long as the question isn't deleted, I do think alternative formulations can be useful `:)`) Cheers!

Comment: @percusse - no worries, closure is good, I got the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As @egreg mentioned, inside the TikZ environment, in order to keep the non code garbage not printed, `\nullfont` is applied. So

```
\tikz{la la laaa. x sdf tgrert}
```

prints nothing. Here you can also use PGF math function `width` too without `calc` but as a stupid side-effect you need to protect the text font switches three times from expansion.

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pagecolor{yellow!15}

\newlength\smlblwid

\def\prepCmds{
  \pgfmathparse{width("\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\tiny 256")}
  \smlblwid=\pgfmathresult pt
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \prepCmds{}

  \begin{axis}[
    x=2*\smlblwid,
  ]
    \addplot {x*0.5};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This won't definitely work if the text doesn't contain just ASCII characters and I'm certain you know it.

Comment: @egreg Indeed also I think the length calculation is wrong now that I think of it. But it's good to get rid of the overhead for simple cases

Comment: Still, I like a lot having an alternative - wasn't aware that there was an alternative width I could have used...